# Invoking a static method over a list of "Class" objects

Tags: java, class, abstract-class, static-methods

my question is more a personnal mind challenge than a production purpose... which means that despite there are obviously better ways to achieve my goal* , I am curious about how - **AND IF** - I could do it this way.
**I am thus not interested in other ways atm*.

I would like to "register" within a list several classes objects (Foo.class, Bar.class, etc.) sharing a common static method inherited from a common parent class.
Then I want to iterate over this list, and invoke that static method.

The following code is wrong indeed, but it may at least show what I am trying to achieve:

========    **Classes definition**

```
public class SomeGenericClass {
   public abstract static String getType();
}
public class SomeSpecializedClassA extends SomeGenericClass{
   public static String getType(){
      return "I am of type A";
   }
}
public class SomeSpecializedClassB extends SomeGenericClass{
   public static String getType(){
      return "I am of type B";
   }
}
```

========    **Main**

```
class Main{

    void main(){
        List<Class<SomeGenericClass>> classes = new ArrayList<Class<SomeGenericClass>> ();
        classes.add(SomeSpecializedClassA.class);
        classes.add(SomeSpecializedClassB.class);
        
        for((SomeGenericClass.class)Class c : classes){
            System.out.println(c.getMethod("getType", null).invoke(null, null));
        }
    }

}
```

========

Any idea?

Comment: There's no such thing as an abstract static method.

Comment: Try this library https://asm.ow2.io/

Comment: Try this library https://asm.ow2.io/
Tools like lombok use this library to inject method into classs. Relavant maven repository.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/asm/asm/3.3.1

Comment: There is not much you have to do to make your code work. Instead of `abstract` throw an exception when calling `SomeGenericClass.getType()`. Now for your other classes return the type. Static methods aren't inherited, but defining a static method with the same name in a subclass will hide the method of the parent class. But overall the whole approach seems wrong. There is rarely a good reason to have methods like getType or stuff like instanceof in your code.

Answer (score 3):

> sharing a common static method inherited from a common parent class.

This is impossible; static methods do not 'do' inheritance, hence why they are called static methods. There is **NO** way to specify that a given class adheres to a spec, where 'the spec' involves 'has static method XYZ'.

Why do you think java has the cliché of having 'factories'? A factory is just a container concept where a single instance of a class is the place you ask questions about the concept of another class: A "PersonFactory" is a class for which usually only a single instance exists and it answers questions about persons in general. Most usually the constructor (which doesn't 'do' specs/interfaces either), but anything else goes too.

> Then I want to iterate over this list, and invoke that static method.

Reflection can do this. It'd be horrible code style, hard to maintain, and all around entirely the wrong way to go about it. You're asking me: "May I have a gun because there is an annoying mosquito balanced on my left toe", and that's the bazooka. If you want to take it and let er rip, okay. Your funeral.

### So what's the better way?

Why is 'static' important here? It's not. Register 'TypeOracle' objects:

```
public interface CommandHandlerFactory {
    String getCommand();
    CommandHandler makeHandler();
}

public interface CommandHandler {
    void handleCommand(UserInfo sendingUser, String cmdData);
}
```

```
public class WelcomeHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleCommand(UserInfo sendingUser, String cmdData) {
      sendMsg("Well hello there, " + sendingUser.getUserName() + "!");
    }
}

channelBot.registerHandler(new CommandHandlerFactory() {
  @Override
  public String getCommand() {
    return "/hello";
  }

  @Override
  public CommandHandler makeHandler() {
    return new WelcomeHandler();
  }
}
```

That's how you do it in a non-blow-your-feet-right-off fashion.

NB: A comment on your question suggest using asm. This is an utterly nonsensical comment; ASM has nothing to do with this and can't help you. Ignore this comment.

Comment: While you can't use a list of Classes without reflection, you could certainly store a list of Runnable method references from the classes, which might be close enough.

Comment: @rzwitserloot note that my question was basic curiosity, not a way to write production code. You answer does point out my many mistakes (with just the right amount of irony and sarcasms that makes it clearer), and your alternative is interesting (at least since I didn't know about such a pattern)